# Solr - {!ex} on a facet query

Tags: solr, lucene

## Background

I'm trying to combine 2 features that work great separately but having trouble making them work together.

*1) As documented on [solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams) I can tag a specific fq and then exclude it on my facet.field. That will make my facets' counts stay the same even when selecting a value, like this:

```
fq={!tag=pt}price:100&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=pt}price
```

*2) I want to use facet.query as follows:

```
facet=true&facet.query=price:[0 TO 100]&facet.query=price:[100 TO *]
```

So I want to combine *1 & *2, this is what I tried:

```
fq={!tag=pt}price:[0 to 100]&facet=true&facet.query={!ex=pt}price:[0 TO 100]&facet.query={!ex=pt}price:[100 TO *]
```

What actually happens is that I receive back from Solr:

```
<lst name="facet_queries">
    <int name="{!ex=pt}price:[0 TO 100]">8</int>
    <int name="{!ex=pt}price:[100 TO *]">19</int>
</lst>
```

## My question is:

Why is the {!ex=pt} part of the name? It's messing up some of my logic.
Maybe I misused it, if so then what's the right way?

## More information

What I am expecting is this: (The same as I receive if running *2 without *1)

```
<lst name="facet_queries">
    <int name="price:[0 TO 100]">8</int>
    <int name="price:[100 TO *]">19</int>
</lst>
```

Which makes sense, since if I'm running *1 this is what I'm receiving in facet_fields:

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="price">
        <int name="80">8</int>
        <int name="150">19</int>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

It doesn't say name="{!ex=pt}price"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this is because:

- `*1` example uses `facet.field` which should be named the same way as the field it uses (without any excludes information).
- `*2` example uses `facet.query` which should represent the `query` (with all possible information used in the query... it would not make sense to display part of query, e.g. without excludes part)

---

Anyway, if there is a need to name the particular facet which uses exclude functionality, then it can be done in the following way(using **key** parameter):

`facet.field={!ex=pt key=good_name_for_a_facet}price`

The same workds for facet.query... E.g., if you *do* want to hide the ex part:

`facet.query={!ex=pt key=$queryOne}price:[0 TO 100]`

where queryOne is part of a raw parameter passed to solr as `queryOne=price:[0 TO 100]`

So the final query will look something like this:

```
fq={!tag=pt}price:[0 TO 100]&facet=true&facet.query={!ex=pt key=$queryOne}price:[0 TO 100]&facet.query={!ex=pt key=$queryTwo}price:[100 TO *]&queryOne=price:[0 TO 100]&queryTwo=price:[100 TO *]
```

---

P.s. I have used the external parameter for key, because in that way - there is not need to do manual escaping of the special characters.

Comment: Working + I now understand the reason behind it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue, and I solved it by adding a local param key to the {!ex} param. So for your example, I would do:

fq={!tag=pt}price:[0 to 100]&facet=true&facet.query={!ex=pt **key="0 TO 100"**}price:[0 TO 100]&facet.query={!ex=pt **key="100 TO *"**}price:[100 TO *]

The reason for this is QueryFacet is treated differently from FieldFacet (facet.field vs facet.query). Solr only removes the local param, which is the {!ex …} in FieldFacet keys. I actually tracked it down to the code for this as you can see in line 680 in FacetComponent.java (v 4.6) from the link below:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_4_6_0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/component/FacetComponent.java?view=markup

I didn't further follow the issue because my use case requires a "pretty" key anyway :)

Comment: Thank you! I chose @rchukh 's  answer since it had more information

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < facetQueries.size(); i++) {
    String value = facetQueries.get(i);
    query.addFacetQuery(String.format("{!ex=%s key=$fQValue_%s}%s", value, i, value));
    query.add(String.format("fQValue_%s", i), value);
}
```